# A couple of questions about a proof of the fact that a linear system has a non-trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$(**)$

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        a_{11}x_1 & + & \ldots & + & a_{1n}x_n & = 0 \\
         \vdots & & & & \vdots\\
        a_{m1}x_1 & + & \ldots & + & a_{mn}x_n & = 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

be a system of $m$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns, and assume that
$n > m$. Then the system has a non-trivial solution.

$Proof$$(incomplete):$

Consider first the case of one equation in $n$ unknowns, $n > 1$:

$a_{1}x_1  +  \ldots + a_{n}x_n  = 0$

If all coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are equal to $0$, then any value of the variables
will be a solution, and a non-trivial solution certainly exists. Suppose
that some coefficient $a_i \neq 0$. After renumbering the variables and the
coefficients, we may assume that it is $a_i$ Then we give $x_2, \ldots, x_n$ arbitrary
values, for instance we let $x_2, \ldots, x_n = 1$ and solve for $x_1$ letting

$x_1 = \frac {-1}{a_1} (a_2 + \ldots + a_n)$

In that manner, we obtain a non-trivial solution for our system of equations.
Let us now assume that our theorem is true for a system of $m - 1$
equations in more than $m - 1$ unknowns. We shall prove that it is true
for $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns when $n > m$. We consider the system
$(**)$.

If all coefficients $(a_{ij})$ are equal to $0$, we can give any non-zero value
to our variables to get a solution. If some coefficient is not equal to $0$,
then after renumbering the equations and the variables, we may assume
that it is $a_{11}$. We shall subtract a multiple of the first equation from the
others to eliminate $x_1$. Namely, we consider the system of equations

$ (A_2 - \frac {a_{21}}{a_{11}} A_1)  \cdot X $

$ (A_m - \frac {a_{m1}}{a_{11}} A_1)  \cdot X $

$\ldots$

---

> We shall subtract a multiple of the first equation from the
>   others to eliminate $x_1$.

Can you, please, explain why?

> $ (A_2 - \frac {a_{21}}{a_{11}} A_1)  \cdot X $

How did they come up with the part inside parenthesis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$A_2$ is the row vector of coefficients for the second equation. It's first entry is "$a_{21}$". So the second equation looks like $a_{21}x_1+\cdots=0$.

Notice that the first equation looks like $a_{11}x_1+\cdots=0$. If we wish to eliminate the variable $x_1$ from the second equation, we can do so by subtracting the appropriate multiple of the first equation.

Specifically: $\dfrac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}\left(a_{11}x_1+\cdots\right)=0$ which is $a_{21}x_1+\cdots=0$. When this is subtracted from the second equation, the resulting equation will no longer have an "$x_1$".

So $A_2 - \dfrac{a_{21}}{a_{11}}A_1$ has zero as its leading entry.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much.